# How to preserve fixed space between two div upon using scale and transform-origin?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to get some help in the following: how to preserve fixed space between two div upon using scale and transform-origin? The divs can be various sizes.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/7dL9sbLk/

HTML:

```
<p>foo</p>
<p class="transformed">bar</p>
<p class="transformed">bar</p>
<p class="transformed">bar</p>
<p class="transformed">bar</p>
<p class="transformed">bar</p>
```

CSS:

```
 p { 
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: teal;
}

.transformed {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: scale(0.58) translateY(0);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Basically, **you can't** without Javascript.

Comment: I'd love to do it with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution with a combination of using Flexbox and Javascript [(Example)](https://jsfiddle.net/b5k7atna/2/):

HTML:

```
<container id='flexbox-container'>
    <div class="transformed">bar</div>
    <div class="transformed">bar</div>
    <div class="transformed">bar</div>
    <div class="transformed">bar</div>
    <div class="transformed">bar</div>
    <div class="transformed">bar</div>
    <div class="transformed">bar</div>
    <div class="transformed">bar</div>
</container>
```

Javascript:

```
document.querySelectorAll( ".transformed" ).forEach( ele => ele.style["margin-bottom" ] = ele.getBoundingClientRect().height - ele.clientHeight + "px")
```

CSS:

```
div { 
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: teal;
}

#flexbox-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.transformed {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: scale(0.48);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set margin-bottom. This is easy for static examples (it would be `margin-bottom: calc( -50px * ( 1 - 0.58 ) );` in your example), but dynamic values need JavaScript. Here is a rough [example](https://jsfiddle.net/b5k7atna/):

```
ele.style[ "margin-bottom" ] = ele.getBoundingClientRect().height -
                               ele.clientHeight + "px";
```

Note you would need to run it every time the element's clientHeight changes (such as a screen rotation or resizing). Various libraries make this easier, such as [css-element-queries](https://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/).